# C++ pow behaviour with negative vector size calculations

Tags: c++, pow

After calling `pow` function with the argument as in the code bellow 
it produces some high number as if it was accessing some invalid memory location.
I have no idea why this happens and any help would be greatly appreciated.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector<vector<int>> G = {
        {1, 2, 3}, 
        {0, 4}
    };
    cout << pow(G[1].size() - G[0].size(), 2) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This prints 1.84467e+019.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type of `.size()` is `unsigned` and you can not simply subtract them when the left operand is less than the right one.

Try this:

```
cout << pow((long) G[1].size() - (long)G[0].size(), 2) << endl;
            ~~~~~~               ~~~~~~
```

However, this solution is based on the assumption that casting the result of `.size()` fits into a `signed long`.

---

If you want a more defensive code, try this one:

```
size_t size_diff(size_t s0, size_t s1)
{
    return s0 < s1? (s1 - s0) : (s0 - s1);
}

int main() {
    // ...   
    cout << pow(size_diff(G[1].size(), G[0].size()), 2) << endl;
}
```

Comment: better cast to float or double, because [pow](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/pow) takes floats anyway.

Comment: @Wolf: I'm not sure for large `size_t` values it produces accurate results if we cast them to `float` first. See [this](http://cpp.sh/8khr4)

Comment: @deepmax In fact I thought of [double](http://cpp.sh/5taht) which has 52 bits mantissa, but you are right: if sizeof(size_t) is 8, this will break. Isn't there maybe some `std::size_diff`?

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the accepted answer, I'd like to note that in C++20 we'll have [`std::ssize()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/size) free function that returns size as a signed type value. Then

```
std::pow(std::ssize(G[1]) - std::ssize(G[0]), 2)
```

will produce the correct result without explicit type casts.

Comment: I afraid it doesn't work because of this: _"If an array is so large (greater than PTRDIFF_MAX elements, but less than SIZE_MAX bytes), that the difference between two pointers may not be representable as std::ptrdiff_t, the result of subtracting two such pointers is undefined. "_ See [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/ptrdiff_t)

Comment: but it explicitly says, there are values which may not be representable as `ptrdiff`, while they're representable as `size_t`.  I am suspicious of C++20  :))

Comment: @deepmax, no overflow can occur here. Any (unsigned) value returned by `size()` is guaranteed to fit into the corresponding signed type (see *[container.requirements.general]* in the standard).

Answer (score 0):

Since [`pow`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/pow) takes a floating point value as its first argument, I'd suggest letting the compiler decide the right promotion by adding the difference to [`0.0` (or `0.0L`)](http://cpp.sh/2ygo):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  std::string name;
  /// 52 of 64 bits used
  uint64_t n1 = 0x000ffffffffffffd;
  uint64_t n2 = 0x000fffffffffffff;

  cout << "plain: " << n1 - n2 << endl;
  cout << "float: " << (float)n1 - (float)n2 << endl;
  cout << "double: " << (double)n1 - (double)n2 << endl;
  cout << "long double: " << (long double)n1 - (long double)n2 << endl;
  cout << "0.0+: " << 0.0 + n1 - n2 << endl;
  cout << "0.0L+: " << 0.0L + n1 - n2 << endl;
  cout << "pow(plain, 2): " << pow(n1-n2, 2) << endl;
  cout << "pow(0.0+diff, 2): " << pow(0.0+n1-n2, 2) << endl;
  cout << "pow(0.0L+diff, 2): " << pow(0.0L+n1-n2, 2) << endl;
}
```

The output

```
plain: 18446744073709551614
float: 0
double: -2
long double: -2
0.0+: -2
0.0L+: -2
pow(plain, 2): 3.40282e+38
pow(0.0+diff, 2): 4
pow(0.0L+diff, 2): 4
```

shows that plain subtraction goes wrong. Even casting to `float` doesn't suffice because `float` provides only a 23-bit mantissa.

The decision whether to use `0.0` or `0.0L` for differences of `size_t` values returned by real `std::vector::size()` calls is theoretical for processes with address spaces below 4.5 Petabytes.

So I think the following will do:

```
cout << pow(0.0 + G[1].size() - G[0].size(), 2) << endl;
```